What is the nutritional composition of edamame peel?
I frequently buy and boil frozen edamame. I eat the beans, and I boil the peel tender, too. I eat the tender and tasty peel. The producer doesn't have to provide the nutritional composition for what it deems a "waste" product. But I'd like to know what nutritional composition the peel has. I can only imagine that it substantially adds to my fibre intake as I prepare about a kilogram of frozen edamame weekly.

Given that it's not generally considered to be food for humans there's likely little data on it as such. If you were a cow, the following might be informative, but it's the dry pod of the fully ripe bean at that point, so it may not be all that similar to the green pod. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26552958_Nutritive_composition_of_soybean_by-products_and_nutrient_digestibility_of_soybean_pod_husk

@Ecnerwal Thanks, that pointed me towards a chapter by M.N. Riaz, in
Encyclopedia of Food and Health, 2016 that also talks about the exploration of the 76% total dietary fiber in human food.

This doesn't appear to be a question about nutritional advice or medical advice, rather a question about the composition of the peel, which can be factually answered.  Just look at the linked questions.  Just because the word "nutritional" appears, doesn't make the question  off limits.

Turns out that soybean hulls are a relatively common source of feed for animals, such as cattle. They contain a high proportion of digestible fibre and can be a partial substitute for grains. So an internet search will yield a fair amount of information.  Here is one such table of an analysis of soybean hulls. Other sources mention the variability in soybeans, so I would assume that other analyses would be in the ballpark, but perhaps not identical.
In this case (just some of the data, for example), on a dry basis:
14.8% crude protein,
3.22% crude fat,
39% crude fibre, and
small amounts of a variety of minerals.

Your answer is helpful. I'd love something that enables me to translate from the dry hull's value to frozen hulls, which still retain moisture and should be significantly less dense.

Note that digestability for a cow (or other ruminant) and for a human are almost certainly different. Unless you get those other 3 stomachs installed, anyway...

I recently eat edamame peels. While most people just eat the beans, the peels do have some benefits worth mentioning.
﻿
But they’re a good source of fiber, which is great for digestion. I noticed that when I include them in my meals, it really helps keep me full longer. They also contain some vitamins, like vitamin C and a few B vitamins, though the amounts aren’t huge.
﻿
I’ve tried incorporating them into smoothies and salads for extra texture and nutrition. They can be a bit tough, so I make sure to cook them well or chop them up.

Can you add a source for your claims of the fiber and vitamin content? (And numbers, if possible, since that was the actual question here.)
